# Dumping $_POST variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a page that has a huge number of checkboxes, the name of the checkboxes are dynamically generated as they convey certain information about each checkbox.

I am trying to view the contents of the posted array with:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

But I am getting an output of:

```
array(0) {}
```

Any ideas on how to display the `$_POST` array? Or maybe transfer it into another array and display it?

Example generated html:

```
<div id="addProductToCollection">
<div id="collection_heading">
Testing
Another Test
Another Test Collection
</div>
<div id="checkboxes">
<form action="127.0.0.1/view_products.php?product=dvds&page=1" name="checkboxes"      method="post">
<div id="collection_row">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,1">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,2">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,3">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,4">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,5">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,6"> 
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,7">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,8">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,9">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="21,dvds,10">
</div>
<div id="collection_row">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,1">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,2">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,3">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,4">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,5">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,6">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,7">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,8">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,9">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="22,dvds,10">
</div>
<div id="collection_row">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,1">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,2">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,3">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,4">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,5">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,6">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,7">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,8">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,9">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="23,dvds,10">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
</div>
```

Solved:

I didn't realise unticked boxes didn't get posted, turns out I needed to tick the checkboxes before posting. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: Post your complete relevant code please.

Comment: You **do** already know how to dump the `$_POST` array, you might want to ask **why** your `$_POST` array is empty - and provide the necessary code to investigate the issue

Comment: Maybe you send your form data via GET instead of POST? Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: You have to check the checkboxes and click on update button. Once form is posted you can view the results var_dump($_POST) in the posted page.

Answer (score 0):

Only checked checkboxes are returned in php $_POST. Try using hidden input if you want all values to be returned.

```
<input name="checkboxstatus[]" type="hidden" value="0">
```

You can manupulate hidden iput values using js.

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is incorrect, that will try and submit to a the current URL /127.0.0.1/view_products.php?product=dvds&page=1.

try this:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1/view_products.php?product=dvds&page=1" name="checkboxes"      method="post">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `print_r($_POST)`

But it looks like it isn't posting any data. Check that your html document that is posting the data is wrapped in `<form action="submit.php" method="post"></form>`

Comment: What difference does it make if you `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` ?

Answer (score -1):

What you want to dump?
You are dumping nothing so it gives empty array. 
ever

```
var_dump($_POST[username]);
```

this will dump username. likewise you can update your code to dump what ever you want

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` dumps ALL the $_POST array, not _nothing_